# How do you link to other razor pages and include a query string parameter in Blazor WASM?

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've got a Blazor WASM app. It has two razor pages:

Documentation.razor:

```
@page "/documentation"
```

ViewRecord.razor:

```
@page "/documentation/ViewRecord"
```

I have a DocumentationController too.

I want to create a few hyperlinks within the Documentation razor page that have hyperlinks in this format:

```
/Documentation/ViewRecord?recordtype=randomWord1
/Documentation/ViewRecord?recordtype=randomWord2
/Documentation/ViewRecord?recordtype=randomWord3
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this, similar to using ActionLinks, instead of having to do something like this:

```
<a href="Documentation/ViewRecord?recordtype=@word1">link1</a>
<a href="Documentation/ViewRecord?recordtype=@word2">link2</a>
<a href="Documentation/ViewRecord?recordtype=@word3">link3</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the beauty of Blazor and Razor Components, if you find you want to something, you can create a re-usable component for it yourself. Complete flexibility. Say for instance we have the following component:

**UrlBuilder.razor**

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FullUrl))
{
    <a href="@FullUrl" class="link">@LinkDesc</a>
}

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string LinkDesc { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string Action { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string UrlParameter { get; set; }
    private string FullUrl { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        FullUrl = $"{Controller}/{Action}?{UrlParameter}";
    }

}
```

You can then access that component anywhere through your application like so:

```
<UrlBuilder LinkDesc="link 1" Controller="Documentation" Action="ViewRecord" UrlParameter="@word3" />
```

[image: Renders]

Is that any easier than creating a a href manually? Absolutely not, however, you could customize it to your delight.